# Does Spirit Bear give reliable or unreliable gold?

Tags: dota-2, dota

With the upcoming changes to Lone Druid's Spirit Bear (i.e. gold bounty from 100 to 300) it's more important to know now - if you get the last hit on an enemy Lone Druid's Spirit Bear, is the gold bounty reliable or unreliable? For some things the bear counts as a hero (i.e. giving reliable gold), and others it counts as a creep (i.e. giving unreliable gold).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now in Dota2, killing Spirit Bear gives unreliable gold.